# Is serializable attribute needed in concrete C# class?

Tags: c#, oop, serializable

In C#, consider we have a *generic* class and a *concrete* class

```
[Serializable]
public class GenericUser
{ ...

[Serializable]
public class ConcreteUser : GenericUser
{ ...
```

is it necessary to mark ConcreteUser as `[Serializable]` or inheritance will take care of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Inherited` is set to `false` with the `[AttributeUsage]` of `SerializableAttribute`, so yes, you need to set it on the concrete class.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you need to mark both, if both are to be binary serialized.